# Move Search Filter to the MenuList

Tags: reactjs, react-select

We're migrating an application from Angular to React. This is a gradual, incremental replacement, so it's critical that the user experience does not change. We decided to go with [react-select](https://react-select.com) as our replacement for [UI-Select](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/). So I'm tasked with creating the implementation.

I've been able to replicate nearly all functionality so far, except some final styling and function on the control.

I am attempting to separate the *inputValue* filter from the root *Control* and move it into the *MenuList*. I realize that I can override both of these Components to customize this functionality. The first hurdle I've encountered is that I cannot add an Input control (any input control) to the MenuList and give it focus. Any 'click' action just bounces off.
[image: Current Layout with non-working, in MenuList search filter]

I'm looking to create something sort of similar to what is seen in the [Experimental popup example](https://react-select.com/advanced#experimental), while keeping my ValueContainer in the core control. Anyone have direction on how to go about this?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you want. Do you have any close example ? Or design to provide ?

Comment: If you look at the attached image (above), you'll see what I'm trying to achieve. Current functionality of react-select is to type directly in the main Container element (blue highlighted box) to filter your options. I need to move that functionality to a 'search box' located in the menu list itself, leaving the main Container solely for display of the ValueContainer (selected option(s)). This is critical to maintain consistent UX with the Angular app, as we gradually update our app to React. (Side Note: That image is react-select, customized to look like our version of UI-Select)

Comment: I saw your picture, it’s just I’m having a hard time figuring the differences with the experimental popup example in React-select documentation

Comment: The Expiremental popup example places the entire Select component in a component similar to a Bootstrap Dropdown Button menu. I'm trying to use the Select as a Select, with the Filter functionaility in the MenuList area of the Select instead of directly in the Container.