# React-Select custom input inside MenuList

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm trying to create a custom select using React-Select options. I would like to have my search not in the control box, but rather in the menu.
I tried this:

```
import React from "react";
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
import { colourOptions, groupedOptions } from "./docs/data";


const MenuList = props => {
  return (
    <components.MenuList {...props}>
      <components.Input {...props} />;
      {props.selectProps.inputValue.length > 1 ? props.children : ""}
    </components.MenuList>
  );
};
export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={colourOptions[1]}
    options={groupedOptions}
    components={{ MenuList }}
  />
);
```

Problem is I'm getting an error saying

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: input is a void element tag and must neither have children nor use dangerouslySetInnerHTML
```

I'm guessing the react select's `components.Input` is rendering another div inside the `input` tag or something like that. 
Does anybody have an idea how this can be done maybe?

Comment: It seems that you have to wrap your Select component input with a `<div>` tag.

Comment: no, doesn't work - https://codesandbox.io/s/xl66k0yr5p

Comment: Remove one brace on the property of Select component: `components={ MenuList }` when you call to MenuList :) Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2rkr0pmj3

Comment: that will just render the default Menu and not my Custom one..

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. Something like I outlined [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765208/move-search-filter-to-the-menulist)? I, and others, have had this [FR in the Issue Tracker for a while now](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3111). First thing you have to realize is that the `Input` component isn't an 'input'.

Comment: It's a little confusing, and takes quite a bit or research reading the 'Components' documentation and reading through the code. The 'input' you see on the screen is a combination of many components, the `Input` being what basically tracks the text cursor and key input.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for. I guess Ill have to track that FR as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### Input as a part of MenuList.

It is inspired by https://codesandbox.io/embed/m75wlyx3oy solution.

Default `MenuList` is exchanged with `CustomMenuWithInput` which in first place show options in dropdown. Options list is provided by `{ props.children }`. Under last option comes input field.

`onFocus={onMenuInputFocus}` prevents from closing dropdown on each letter typed in input.

```js
const CustomMenuWithInput = ({ selectProps: { onMenuInputFocus }, ...props }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      { props.children }
      <input
        id='add-option'
        label='Add option'
        placeholder='option'
        autoCorrect='off'
        autoComplete='off'
        spellCheck='false'
        type='text'
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
        onMouseDown={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation()
          e.target.focus()
        }}
        onFocus={onMenuInputFocus}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

const SelectView = ({ onChange }) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false)

  return (
    <Select
      id=''
      label={'List'}
      options={list}
      onChange={opt => {
        onChange(opt.value, opt)
        setIsFocused(false)
      }}
      onInputChange={setInputValue}
      onMenuInputFocus={() => setIsFocused(true)}
      inputValue={inputValue}
      placeholder='Select...'
      components={{
        MenuList: CustomMenuWithInput,
      }}
      isSearchable
      {...{
        menuIsOpen: isFocused || undefined,
        isFocused: isFocused || undefined
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You should inspire yourself with what's suggested in the documentation in the section `Advanced` here: https://react-select.com/advanced.

I have recreated a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmrvj7mv77) in CodeSandbox so you can see it in action and play with it. But the main idea is to embed the original `Select` element inside some controlled element and them edit the style of your `Select` to make it feel as one single `MenuList`.

```
class PopoutExample extends Component<*, State> {
  state = { isOpen: false, value: undefined };
  toggleOpen = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ isOpen: !state.isOpen }));
  };
  onSelectChange = value => {
    this.toggleOpen();
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  render() {
    const { isOpen, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <Dropdown
        isOpen={isOpen}
        onClose={this.toggleOpen}
        target={
          <Button
            iconAfter={<ChevronDown />}
            onClick={this.toggleOpen}
            isSelected={isOpen}
          >
            {value ? `State: ${value.label}` : "Select a State"}
          </Button>
        }
      >
        <Select
          autoFocus
          backspaceRemovesValue={false}
          components={{ DropdownIndicator, IndicatorSeparator: null }}
          controlShouldRenderValue={false}
          hideSelectedOptions={false}
          isClearable={false}
          menuIsOpen
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
          options={stateOptions}
          placeholder="Search..."
          styles={selectStyles}
          tabSelectsValue={false}
          value={value}
        />
      </Dropdown>
    );
  }
}

// styled components

const Menu = props => {
  const shadow = "hsla(218, 50%, 10%, 0.1)";
  return (
    <div
      css={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        borderRadius: 4,
        boxShadow: `0 0 0 1px ${shadow}, 0 4px 11px ${shadow}`,
        marginTop: 8,
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 2
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
};
const Blanket = props => (
  <div
    css={{
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      position: "fixed",
      zIndex: 1
    }}
    {...props}
  />
);
const Dropdown = ({ children, isOpen, target, onClose }) => (
  <div css={{ position: "relative" }}>
    {target}
    {isOpen ? <Menu>{children}</Menu> : null}
    {isOpen ? <Blanket onClick={onClose} /> : null}
  </div>
);
const Svg = p => (
  <svg
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    focusable="false"
    role="presentation"
    {...p}
  />
);
const DropdownIndicator = () => (
  <div css={{ color: colors.neutral20, height: 24, width: 32 }}>
    <Svg>
      <path
        d="M16.436 15.085l3.94 4.01a1 1 0 0 1-1.425 1.402l-3.938-4.006a7.5 7.5 0 1 1 1.423-1.406zM10.5 16a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11z"
        fill="currentColor"
        fillRule="evenodd"
      />
    </Svg>
  </div>
);
const ChevronDown = () => (
  <Svg style={{ marginRight: -6 }}>
    <path
      d="M8.292 10.293a1.009 1.009 0 0 0 0 1.419l2.939 2.965c.218.215.5.322.779.322s.556-.107.769-.322l2.93-2.955a1.01 1.01 0 0 0 0-1.419.987.987 0 0 0-1.406 0l-2.298 2.317-2.307-2.327a.99.99 0 0 0-1.406 0z"
      fill="currentColor"
      fillRule="evenodd"
    />
  </Svg>
);
```

Comment: I like this, I did something similar once, for MultiSelect it gets a bit more problematic if you want all the styling of the react-select, I was hoping for a more simple solution, but I guess it does not exist.

Comment: For multi select you will have to put a lot of effort to fake the `Select` with the `Dropdown` element. React-select can be really powerful and customizable but not that simple.

Comment: Based off of this solution I tweaked it a bit: https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-react-select-2-rtf1l